# SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync is not returning all results?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I’m writing a tool for searching inside solutions. For this purpose I’m using SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync and for finding class usages it is working like a charm. But When I started searching for method invocations I'm not getting all results.

So for example when in project A I have class X whit method Add() when I’m using this method in project A all references could be found. But when I’m adding  project A reference to project B (inside the same solution) and then I’m using method Add() then references are not found. When I’m looking for references of class X everything is working. All test project A and B are compiling in VS.
Pseudo code I’m using looks like this:

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
var project = solution.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == “ProjectName”);
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
var containingTypeSymbol = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(“TypeName”);
var searchedSymbol = containingTypeSymbol.GetMembers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == “MethodName”);
var results = await SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(searchedSymbol, solution);
```

Full example can be found here: https://github.com/bigdnf/DependencyFinder/blob/master/SymbolFinder/SourceFinder/SourceFinder/Program.cs
Console app is getting only references to Svalve class but there are no parent invocations on the result list?